# How to get a handle of a label in a window

Tags: winapi

How to get a handle of a label in a window.
I try spy4win and spy++, they dont work.
[image]

Comment: Note that if the program under consideration uses many flavors of .net (basically anything xaml-based) individual components will not have HWND of their own, you'll need to interact with them in some other way. Your best bet from a native program would likely be UIA.

Comment: But why the button or the progress bar have the HWND?

Comment: Not all controls are windowed. If this was a Delphi VCL app (and the app icon is a bit of a tell that it is) then it would have the behaviour you observe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Spy++ cannot identify a `HWND` for a UI element then there isn't one. Several UI toolkits (such as Qt) use window-less controls.

Your only option in this case is to use [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32). It provides a framework for identifying user interface elements that doesn't rely on native windows. You can use the [Inspect.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/inspect-objects) tool to verify whether the application in question implements the required interfaces.

If the application doesn't implement the UI Automation interfaces, there's little you can do, outside of taking a screenshot and trying to identify UI elements based on pixel data, and extracting text by means of [OCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition).

Comment: It is written by Delphi language with TLabel class.

Comment: Neither the programming language nor the UI framework are of any relevance. Ultimately, any GUI implementation will have to call into the OS, and there are only two cases to consider: The program uses native controls, or the program doesn't use native controls. If it uses native controls, a program can retrieve a native window handle (`HWND`) for a control. If it doesn't, then a program cannot retrieve a native window handle. There isn't anything to retrieve. You are in the latter bracket.